# How do I Export Phabricator Diff HTML for history and logs

Tags: export, phabricator

I'm going to be transitioning to another diff tool and no longer use Phabricator, however, my organization wants to keep a history of all the Diffs and the approvals processes that happened in Phabricator. Does anyone know how to export it into HTML, or a format that is good for reading like a log?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could get the Diffs with a conduit call like `differential.querydiffs`.
2. Then extract the  HTML part and build a single file per Diff.

Conduit Example:

```
$ echo '{
  "ids": [
    "362"
  ]
}' | arc call-conduit --conduit-uri <phabricator-uri> --conduit-token <conduit-token> differential.querydiffs
```

Comment: This really doesn't produce HTML.  Nor does it actually dump the full contents of the differential, including comments.   At least, it doesn't for my version of phabricator.